# C: 2d char pointer in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I want to write and print some strings in a 2d array in a struct. The struct is called Router and it is in a header file, the 2d array is defined in that struct and it's called **addTab. When I try to print one line of the array using the function viewTable the program stopped working... why?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "router.h"
#define N 8
#define M 3
#define sizeMess 5

Router *createRouter(){
    Router *NewRouter=(Router*)malloc(sizeof(Router));
    int i;
    NewRouter->addTab=(char **) malloc(N*sizeof(char *));
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        NewRouter->addTab[i]=(char *) malloc(M*sizeof(char));
    return NewRouter;
}


void viewTable(Router *r, int a){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<M;j++){
            printf("raw\t col\t address\t value\t\n");
            printf("%d\t %d\t",i,j);
            printf("%p\t",&r->addTab[i][j]);
            printf("%s\t\n",r->addTab[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
void updateTable(Router *r, int conn, char *addr1, char *addr2){
    r->addTab[conn][1]=addr1;
    r->addTab[conn][2]=addr2;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the definition of your `Router` struct?

Comment: You're allocating `M` number of elements, each of size `sizeof(char)`, and then storing a `char*` pointer in them -- that doesn't seem right...

Comment: Please provide a "working" (whatever that means) example of your problem.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in this code

Comment: how do you think to make 2d allocated array @Badministrator

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname That depends how he wants to use the array, but somehow I don't think he wants to store strings of 1 byte in that array...

Comment: stops working means that once completed and launched the program , the operating system ( Windows ) started the research of the problem because the program does not work properly... I do not know the correct definition but that's what happens

Comment: @jack How are you calling your `updateTable` function?

Comment: Side note: there's no such thing as a 2D pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: [Don't cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Assuming that you want to store `char*` pointers in your 2D array (as the title of your question says), you will need to define it as `char ***` in your `Router` structure, like this:

```
typedef struct router {
    char ***addTab;
} Router;
```

Next, you will need to change your `createRouter` function, so that it can store an array of `char*` pointers, instead of a single byte for each element, like so:

```
Router *createRouter(){
    Router *NewRouter=malloc(sizeof(Router));
    int i;
    NewRouter->addTab=malloc(N*sizeof(char **));
    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
        NewRouter->addTab[i]=malloc(M*sizeof(char *));
    return NewRouter;
}
```

I'm not sure how you call your `updateTable` function, but unless you actually fill up the entire array with `char*` pointers, your `viewTable` function will also invoke [Undefined Behavior](http://c-faq.com/ansi/undef.html), because the `printf` statements will attempt to access uninitialized data. You could avoid this by using `calloc` instead of `malloc` when allocating the 2D array (or explicitly `memset` it), and then adding NULL checks in your `viewTable` function.

Finally, if you're calling `updateTable` with `char*` pointers that are not string literals or they have not been allocated on the heap, you might have further issues...

Comment: thanks a lot! I know i shuold avoid this but thank you very much. i use calloc for the 2d(3d?) array and it works perfectly. grazie!!!

Comment: No problem. :) FWIW, it's still a 2D array, but of pointers, instead of single bytes (which is what you had before).

Answer (score 0):

Your updateTable() doesn't work as you'd expect. You allocated memory in `r->addTab[i][j]` and, afterwards, assign a pointer to it (`r->addTab[conn][1]=addr1`). On access in viewTable, the program tries to read the memory at `addr1`, but most likely won't be able to read it, thus crashes.

Use a function to copy a given string to r->addTab, e.g. like so:

```
void router_tab_printf(Router *r, const int conn, const int i, const char *value) {
    sprintf(r->addTab[conn][i], "%s", value);
}
```

This assumes that `r->addTab[conn][i]` is large enough to hold `value`.

Comment: still doesn't work.. i have this warning "passing argument 1 of 'sprintf' makes pointer from integer without a cast".

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your updateTable

```
void updateTable(Router *r, int conn, char *addr1, char *addr2){
strcpy(r->addTab[conn], addr1);
strcpy(r->addTab[conn+1 /*or something*/], addr2);
}
```